# How to set multiple TextView's size

Tags: android

I have many `TextView's` in `ViewHolder`
 
like :

```
holder.ID1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lbID1);
holder.ID2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lbID2);
holder.ID3 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lbID3);
holder.ID4 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lbID4);  and so on....
```

There property and size is define in `style.xml` and `dimens.xml`. Now I want to set there size based on setting like **Small,** **Medium** and **Large**. This is the `Integer` value which I receive on login, but I Know

> It is not possible to set the values for the dimen variables in my `dimen.xml` file programmatically from my `activity`.

So One way is to set there size like this :

```
setSize(holder.ID1, Size);   
setSize(holder.ID2, Size);
setSize(holder.ID3, Size);
setSize(holder.ID4, Size); and so on....


public void setSize(TextView textView, int size) {
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size);
}
```

Which is so long process. Is there any other way which is **Sort** and **Good** ???

Comment: Just use `dimens.xml` and set text size in xml . Or you can use style for each of your text view like smallStyle, largeStyle and so on .'

Comment: but on login i received size in integer value. so how i can use if condition in style.xml or dimens.xml

Comment: Then go with `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` .setTextSize is just one code and you need to call it on every view so i think you can call it individually. No need for Utility class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use custom `TextView`

`CustomTextView.java`

```
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

String Size;

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView,0,0);

    try{

        Size = ta.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_ctv_size);

        if (Size.equals("small")){

            this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14);
        }else{
            this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);

        }

    }finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }

}

public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
 }
```

add **attr.xml** file to your values directory and this code in it:

```js
 <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="ctv_size" format="string"/>
 </declare-styleable>
```

Then use it as a view in your XML

```js
  <com....CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:ctv_size="small"/>
```

It will work properly and smooth... Cheers....

Comment: You can use other options such as medium and big... and for all of them, you can set other textview size value...

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a helper function which accepts a holder and size.
2. In helper function then search for every child in a loop.
3. If child view is a TextView, cast it to TextView and call setTextSize function with size passed in the helper in step 1.

Comment: This could work, but won't be suitable since the OP would like a short solution without having to deal with every text view.

Comment: he doesn't have to deal with every text view. Only write it once. In loop that code executes on every textview